# Cannot invoke "Int" with an argument of type "String"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

When I use this code from apple book in my playground:

```
let possibleNumber = "123"
let convertedNumber = Int(possibleNumber)
```

Xcode shows an error:

> Cannot invoke "Int" with an argument of type "String"

But compiler should refer `convertedNumber` as optional, as I understand.

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Xcode are you using? I'm on 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You must be using Swift 1.x (in Xcode 6), but the Swift book is for the last version of Swift, currently 2.1 (in Xcode 7). The String initializer for Int() wasn't available in Swift 1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work with no issues. It could be the XCode causing the issue. Try a reinstallation of the XCode.